# Longest shortest path in an undirected unweighted graph

Tags: graph-theory

**PROBLEM**

I have an **undirected unweighted graph** and I would like to find the **longest shortest path** in that graph (in other words, for each two vertices I can calculate the minimal distance between them, and I want to find maximum over all those distances).

**SOLUTION ATTEMPT**

I've search for graph width, range, span -- but all those terms refer to something different.

Comment: What you want is called **diameter**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All considered graphs are finite, simple and undirected. Let $G=(V,E)$ be such a graph on $n$ vertices.

The minimum length of the paths connecting two vertices $v_x,v_y \in V$ is called the *distance* between $v_x$ and $v_y$ and is denoted by $d(v_x, v_y)$. If $G$ is disconnected and $v_x$ and $v_y$ are not in the same components, we define $d(v_x,v_y)=\infty$.

The $n \times n$ - *graph distance matrix* $D=(d_{xy})$ consists of all graph distances from vertex $v_x$ to vertex $v_y$. The maximum value of all entries of $D$ is called the *diameter* of $G$.

**Example:** Given $G=(V,E)$. Let $V=\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n\}$ and $E=\{(v_1,v_2),(v_2,v_3), (v_2,v_5),(v_2,v_4)\}$. The $(x,y)^{th}$ entry of the distance matrix $D$ of $G$ is the distance $d(v_x,v_y)$, yielding in

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    2 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
    2 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
    2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}$$

Now, finding the diameter using the distance matrix $D$ is easy.

**Question:** How do we calculate $D$?

We could use [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) which runs in $O(n^3)$.

But since our graphs are undirected and unweighted, we can do better. There is an algorithm by Chan solving our problem for an unweighted and undirected graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges in [$O(nm)$](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2344422.2344424).

Yamane and Kobayashi implemented an algorithm for unweighted graphs in general. Their paper contains a small list of known algorithms solving the same problem. You can find a preprint on arXiv [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.06806).